# C++ Xersers removeChildnode and flush leaves an empty line

Tags: c++, dom, xerces

**Env setup :**
Using Xersers and DOM Parsers.
Implementation in  C++.
OS - SUSE Linux

**Problem :**
The `DOMNode::removeChildNode(DOMNode*)` is invoked to remove a specific node (I am speaking of valid node , available deletion. No exception scenario). Later the data is written into using the `DOMWriter DOMWriter::writeNode(&targetm,DOMDocument)`.

a. When I open the file after operation, I see that instead of removing a node, it has been replaced by empty line.
b. If the operations are carried over multiple times, then the xml file will be filled with empty lines. Each add does not use these empty lines, but instead will use a new line, extending the parent node.

I think I am missing some attribute setting, but not able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you remove element nodes, leaving whitespace text nodes around? In terms of text, you're removing starting from the `<` of the opening tag and up to the `>` of the closing one.